# What's wrong with my UV map?

Tags: uv

I'm working on texturing a model and noticed the textures looked off. I applied the UV checker as a texture and noticed that there was definitely something wrong with some triangles (but not whole quads).

In this screenshot I've selected an offending area. As you can see, half the quad is "smeared."

[image]

What could be causing this? The uv map was generated using UV unwrap after marking the seams.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is some sort of a uv stretching problem. You can find where it is by enabling "Stretch" in the uv editor:

[image]

Blue is what you want, green is okay, and orange/red is really bad.

My guess is that your problem is in this region, but I can't say this for sure unless you post your blend:

[image]

Edit:

The problem is that those are N-gons on the side. You need to remove all of the N-gons to unwrap successfully. I just triangulated, then removed the edge cutting across the center to make it a quad:

[image]

Then unwrap, and voila.

Here is the blend:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion re: stretching. I've added a link to the blend. The stretching shows up here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/1XGwBBg.png). Overall, there's not much stretching, except on those three panels. But why? The uv for those areas looks like a good fit for the model.

Also, one of the panels that shows the problem is solid blue-- no stretching at all.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a setting to warn that an object has ngons and won't unwrap properly?

Comment: To check this, go into edit mode, then go to "Select > Select All by Trait". Disable "Extend", set number of vertices to 4, and set the type to "Greater Than". All n-gons will be selected.